# Hugo: .Data.Pages works in Blog.html context but fails in another context

Tags: hugo

In **blog.html** partial, I have:

```
            {{ range first 1 (where .Data.Pages "Type" "post") }}
                <div class="ph1-ns w-50-ns flex">
                    {{ .Render "li" }}
                </div>
            {{ end }}
```

which successfully pulls data for one blog post.

I have another partial **comic.html** with the exact same code:

```
    {{ range first 1 (where .Data.Pages "Type" "post") }}
        <div class="ph1-ns w-50-ns flex">
                {{ .Render "li" }}
        </div>
    {{ end }}
```

but this fails with the message:

> 2:18:57 PM: ERROR 2018/08/11 04:18:57 Error while rendering "section": template: /opt/build/repo/site/layouts/section/products.html:3:3: executing "main" at <partial "jumbotron" ...>: error calling partial: template: partials/jumbotron.html:6:11: executing "partials/jumbotron.html" at <partial "comic" .>: error calling partial: template: partials/comic.html:6:19: executing "partials/comic.html" at <where .content.Data....>: error calling where: can't iterate over <nil>

**Notes:**

- blog partial is directly called from index.html using:
  `{{ partial "blog" . }}`
- comic partial is indirectly called from index html via jumbotron.html
  *index.html:*
  `{{ partial "jumbotron" (dict "imageUrl" .Params.image "title" .Title "subtitle") }}`
  *jumbotron.html:*
  `{{ partial "comic" . }}`

I suspected this might have been caused by not passing the context to jumbotron, so tried in jumbotron.html:

`{{ partial "jumbotron" (dict "imageUrl" .Params.image "title" .Title "subtitle" .Params.subtitle "content" .) }}`

and then pulled that context with `.content` i.e.

`{{ range first 1 (where .content.Data.Pages "Type" "post") }}`

but this also didn't work. I even tried declaring a variable using `.Site.GetPage`
and then referencing this variable for the .Data.Pages data, but it didn't work. **Any help would be appreciated.**